# Making manifold meshes from Google Map data imported from RenderDoc+MapsModelsImporter

Tags: modeling, edit-mode, topology

There's a Blender addon called [MapsModelsImporter](https://github.com/eliemichel/MapsModelsImporter) which imports data exported from Google Maps via [RenderDoc](https://renderdoc.org/).
Using this, I extracted parts of a city, resulting in 1.7 million or faces. Most of the faces overlap but as you can imagine there are many artifacts, internal faces, and non-manifold geometry.

I can use a Boolean modifier easily enough to cut chunks out but I'm having trouble making a manifold mesh so it can be 3d printed.

#### What I've tried so far:

The following was attempted but with limited success. Before each of these attempts, I put up some faces to roughly outline the base, join all the meshes with `Object` > `Join`, delete loose vertices and edges with `Mesh` > `Clean Up` > `Delete Loose`, and remove double vertices with `Mesh` > `Clean Up` > `Merge By Distance`.

- Apply a `Remesh` modifier. This works the best so far but misses some details. It's a lot of manual work to try to get the modifier to pick up missing details.
- Use `Face` > `Intersect (Knife)` and `Mesh` > `Clean Up` > `Merge By Distance` (tried both settings: self-intersect as well as intersecting with the base). There are so many faces that multiple passes are needed because only a subset of cuts are made in a given execution. This also blows up the number of vertices.
- Use `Object Data Properties` > `Remesh` > `Mode: Voxel` > `Voxel Remesh`. Wasn't able to successfully complete the execution from this. RAM + VRAM totalled over 100 GB and Blender quits.
- Select the edges using edge loop select and use `F` to create faces around the edge. Because the imported meshes are made up of discontinuous grids, it's not easy to select the boundary. Also, this doesn't address the issues in the centre of the mesh.
- Use external tools such as MeshMixer, Instant Meshes, Cura, and Slic3r. Was not able to succeed with any of these.

#### Question:

What's the best way of making such a mesh manifold?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: No not yet @Nigel sorry. I've tabled this project but will get back to it eventually.